# Split and concatenating in unix

Tags: unix

UNIX:

I have to load file contents to one table when it will find the tag:

```
ACC2020000
```

Contents in file:

```
ACC2020000 ALEJA B JURI
```

Tried with below  code :

```
if(substr($_,0,10) eq 'ACC2020000') 
{
    $ADDRESS1= (split(" ",$_))[1];   
}
```

Output : `ALEJA`

Expected Output : `ALEJA B JURI`

Can anyone suggest how to get the correct output?

Comment: What language did you use?

Comment: Why not `$ADDRESS1 = substr($_, 11)`?  I'm making a guess that the language you're using is Perl.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `grep` and `cut` easily, assuming there is a space after the `ACC2020000` pattern:

```
grep '^ACC2020000' file | cut -f2- -d' '
```